# Dynamic banners not loading after cache clear

Tags: magento2, product, cache, image, banner

Can some one please help me here. I cleared the Product images cache as many images were incorrect.
I'm unable to recall the cache. The main dynamic banners on the homepage are not loading.
I ran the product resize image command and cleared cache.